# How do I achieve button smooth background transition on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've been working my random quote generator project and I want to achieve the effect that when I touch the button on mobile device the background color become semi-transparent.
here is my code. 
there is a button id="loadQuote"

```
#loadQuote {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6em;
  bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: .5s ;
}

#loadQuote:active {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 10ms linear;
     transition: background-color 10ms linear;
}
```

I tried this out on google chrome emulator and it worked out fine but when I actually tried this on my iphone it doesn't have the effect as it should. I cannot think of why.
and another weird thing is, at first I set the duration over which transitions should occur to 1000ms, the background changed really fast then I set them to be 10ms as in this case, the change appears much slowly and more noticeable. I was wondering why, shouldn't the animation last longer when the duration time is longer?

Here is the live demo for the project.
https://zhenghaohe.github.io/random-quote-generator/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why your transition don't work all the time:

a) you have only defined them on the `:active` state of the element (so they only apply when the element is in that state). When it's not, it doesn't transition. And

b) you shouldn't rely on `:active` on mobile devices. It's recommended you add (and remove) a class. So let's set transitions on the bare element (without class) and use a class to control the on/off state.

To demonstrate, I've also added some JavaScript, but if you already got that covered, disregard it.

```js
let lQ = document.querySelector('#loadQuote');

lQ.addEventListener('click', activatelQ);
lQ.addEventListener('tap', activatelQ);

function activatelQ(){
  lQ.classList.add('active');
  deactivatelQ();
}

function deactivatelQ() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    lQ.classList.remove('active')
  },731)
}
```

```css
#loadQuote {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6em;
  bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: background-color .5s linear;

  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadQuote.active {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="loadQuote">Some quote</div>
```

Looking at your website, I see you're using jQuery. So disregard the above JavaScript and make the following mods to your jQuery:

1. Replace `$('#loadQuote').click(generateQuote);` with

```js
 $('#loadQuote').on('click tap', function(){
   $(this).addClass('active');
   generateQuote()
 }
```

2. Add this line inside your `renderQuote()` function:

```js
$('#loadQuote').removeClass('active');
```

---

On a different note, in the future, try to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. Answerers should not have to view your website in order to answer. Besides, your website will change, leaving the question irrelevant for future users. If you're not willing to help others, by keeping the question relevant, you shouldn't expect much help yourself.

Comment: Thanks!!! You've been a big help! can I just ask another question: when I view this web app on my phone it doesn't run really smoothly. I was wondering if it has something to do with loading the gif file since it's quite big. how can I improve this?

Comment: Look up the [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src) attribute. And don't ask two questions in one in the future. Answering the second would mean I don't help everyone else wanting to find the answer to it, as they'll never find it in these comments. Happy coding!